# Javascript get Scope/Context of caller without passing it

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I am using meteorjs and there are so called `publications` and `meteor methods`. Inside of these you can access a variable `this.connection` that holds information about all the http headers and connection you have with the specific user, for example the hostname over which they got access to your site.

As I want to make my application multidomain like slack, I now need to hook the database methods to limit the returned dataset to the right hostname.

Problem: This data is only available inside of the poblication or meteor method.

Is there any way to get the `this` of the calling method without changing the signatures of all my model functions?

Example:

```
mySpecialMethodWhereThisIsRight = function(param1) {
  console.log(this.connection.httpHeaders.host) //Prints out the servername
  modelname.mySelfMadeFunction(someData);
}

modelname = {
  mySelfMadeFunction: function (data) {
    console.log(this.connection.httpHeaders.host) //prints nothing

    # some voodo
    console.log(this.connection.httpHeaders.host) //Prints out the hostname
  }
}
```

I am now looking for that "voodo" otherwise I would have to rewrite a lot of functions and the places they are called. (not that easy as there is no refactoring tool for coffeescript that actually works reliably)

Comment: You can use `arguments.caller`, but it's obsolete.

Comment: Problem is that i cannot easily pass more arguments now as I would need to refactor around 30k lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood, but if you're able to make changes to the calling methods, would this work for you?

```js
mySpecialMethodWhereThisIsRight = function(param1) {
  console.log(this.connection.httpHeaders.host) //Prints out the servername
  modelname.mySelfMadeFunction.bind(this)(someData);
}
```

Comment: it's not the perfect solution but better only rewrite 10k lines of models than 10k lines of models plus 20k lines of calls to these models

Comment: is there probably a way to open a scope in my parent method that i can access some functions deeper in the tree without binding it?